# What is the best way to post input data and insert them to the database with ajax in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I developed a contact form with pure PHP and HTML. I wanna insert the input values into the database with AJAX. Here is my **Javascript/jQuery** code:

```js
var email = jQuery("#email").val();

var data = {
    'email': email
}            

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mywebsitedomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/contactform.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success : function(data) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

And my contactform.php:

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('myTableName', array(
    'email' => $_POST["email"],
    'date' => $date,
));
```

My code works well. My question is what is the correct way to do that? Because I think it's not a good idea to create a .php file inside the WordPress theme and use it just for inserting data into the database. I think it has security issues and users can see my script URL (http://mywebsitedomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/contactform.php) that used in my javascript file for using ajax.

Do you have better ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for inserting data and also enqueue script for ajax call and pass it in url. example like:

```
function mytheme_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/admin_script.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','mytheme_admin_scripts' );
```

Enqueue your js file which you have wrote your ajax call and pass my_ajax_object.ajx_url in your ajax url.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url :  my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success : function(data) {
              // do something
        }
        });
```